# Example of a Monoid with two distinct congruence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

I am looking for an example of a monoid $M$ with identity element $e$ and two distinct congruence relations $R \neq R'$ on $M$.

I feel that I need a non-cancellative Monoid, but I am struggling here.

Comment: Why? Do you know a group with two different normal subgroups? Every group is a (cancellative) monoid and normal subgroups are in canonical one-to-one correspondence with congruences.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for each monoid $M$, the identity relation $\{(a,a)\mid a\in M\}$ and the all-relation $\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in M\}$ are congruence relations, the trivial ones.

Answer (score 2):

Although Wuestenfux's answer is perfectly correct, if you want to avoid trivial congruences, start with any nontrivial monoid $M$ and consider the monoid $M \times M$. Now define
\begin{align}
  (x_1, x_2)\sim_1 (y_1, y_2) &\iff x_1 = y_1 \\
  (x_1,x_2) \sim_2 (y_1, y_2) &\iff x_2 = y_2
\end{align}
Then both $\sim_1$ and $\sim_2$ are congruences on $M \times M$, and you can choose $M$ (and hence $M \times M$) to be cancellative if you wish.